# This python "Tic-Tac-Toe" program is suffering from a chronic case of "programmer does not know what happened"

Tags: python, hashmap, set, tic-tac-toe

Code here(does this violate guidelines?)

```py
import random
def show_board(board):
  print(f'''
  +-------+-------+-------+
  |       |       |       |
  |   {board[1]}   |   {board[2]}   |   {board[3]}   |
  |       |       |       |
  +-------+-------+-------+
  |       |       |       |
  |   {board[4]}   |   {board[5]}   |   {board[6]}   |
  |       |       |       |
  +-------+-------+-------+
  |       |       |       |
  |   {board[7]}   |   {board[8]}   |   {board[9]}   |
  |       |       |       |
  +-------+-------+-------+
  ''')
def player_move(board): 
  while True:
    try:
      x= int(input("What is your move? "))
    except:
      continue
    if board[x] in ['O', 'X']:
      continue
    elif x < 0 or x > 10:
      continue
    else:
      board[x] = 'O'
      break

def comp_move(board):
  board[random.choice([k for k,v in board.items() if v != 'O' and v != 'X'])] = 'X'
def move_chck(board):
  win_conditions = [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}, {1, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 7}]
  comp_moves = {v for k, v in board.items() if v == 'X'}
  player_moves = {v for k, v in board.items() if v == 'O'}
  for condition in win_conditions:
    if comp_moves.issuperset(condition):
      return "Computer won"
      break
    elif player_moves.issuperset(condition):
      return 'Player won'
      break
    elif len(comp_moves) + len(player_moves) == 9:
      return 'Draw'
      break
    else:
      return 'Continue'
      break
def main():
  board = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 'X', 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}
  while True:
    show_board(board)
    player_move(board)
    r = move_chck(board)
    if r == 'Continue':
      pass
    else:
      print(r)
      break
    comp_move(board)
    r = move_chck(board)
    if r == 'Continue':
      pass
    else:
      print(r)
      break
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The code runs without any errors, however when a win or tie occurs, it is not outputted to the console, it just continues to run. I know my code is a little janky and complicated but could somebody help me out here?

I believe that the `pass` used in the main() function is most likely the reason there is no output. As stated above, no runtime or syntax error occurs. When I look at the `r` variable which contains the result, no matter what happens in the code, it always evaluates to 'Continue'

If anyone would like the specifics, this is Edube Interactive Project 4.7.2.1, Aligned with PCEP-30-02

Comment: Tons of tic-tac-toe stuff present online. **Don't use a sword when needle might suffice!**

Comment: @taurus05 believe me, I tried looking for solutions online but I couldn't find any for this specific problem

Comment: Test your `move_chck` function separately instead of in-game, with a known input and known expected output.

Comment: @Axe319 So I need to move the `return 'Continue'`out of the loop?

Comment: There is no need for any *"programmer does not know what happened"* since the day debugging tools were invented. Did you use one to step through the code, set break points, inspect variables, ...etc?

Comment: @Axe319 thanks for helping me, I happen to be new to Stack Overflow, and I wasn't sure if someone would help me. On a related note, do you know how to accept someone's answer?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, and you can accept that if you feel it was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `move_chck` function has a few problems.

The first being, that it only ever iterates once.

```py
def move_chck(board):
  win_conditions = [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}, {1, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 7}]
  comp_moves = {v for k, v in board.items() if v == 'X'}
  player_moves = {v for k, v in board.items() if v == 'O'}
  for condition in win_conditions:
    if comp_moves.issuperset(condition):
      return "Computer won"
      break
    elif player_moves.issuperset(condition):
      return 'Player won'
      break
    elif len(comp_moves) + len(player_moves) == 9:
      return 'Draw'
      break
    else: # this condition always defaults to matching on every iteration
      return 'Continue'
      break
```

To fix this portion you, you can move the default condition out of your `for` loop. I've also removed the `break`s since those are never reached either. A `return` statement stops the execution of a function immediately and is what's known as an "early `return`".

```
def move_chck(board):
  win_conditions = [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}, {1, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 7}]
  comp_moves = {v for k, v in board.items() if v == 'X'}
  player_moves = {v for k, v in board.items() if v == 'O'}
  for condition in win_conditions:
    if comp_moves.issuperset(condition):
      return "Computer won"
    elif player_moves.issuperset(condition):
      return 'Player won'
    elif len(comp_moves) + len(player_moves) == 9:
      return 'Draw'
  return 'Continue'
```

Your second problem is that you're creating a `set` of all board values. Those `set`s will only ever be `{"X"}` or `{"O"}`. So, the final fix is using the keys instead.

```
def move_chck(board):
  win_conditions = [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}, {1, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 7}]
  comp_moves = {k for k, v in board.items() if v == 'X'}
  player_moves = {k for k, v in board.items() if v == 'O'}
  for condition in win_conditions:
    if comp_moves.issuperset(condition):
      return "Computer won"
    elif player_moves.issuperset(condition):
      return 'Player won'
    elif len(comp_moves) + len(player_moves) == 9:
      return 'Draw'
  return 'Continue'
```